# Docker php can't run proprerly crontab

Tags: php, docker, cron

I run a docker php container to show a website. I'm using the php:5.6-apache image and then in the Dockerfile I put theses lines :

```
# Setup crontab
ADD ./crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

This works very well, if in the crontab file I put a line to put a hello world in a file, then the process works but I can't access anymore to my website.
If i try to write localhost i get a "can't access to the server error" like there is no server running.

If i comment "CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log", then i can now reach the server but the crontab not work anymore...

What can i do ?

Comment: Yeah, since you've overridden the CMD entrypoint. Can you not just use `RUN` with just `cron`?

Comment: `RUN` just `cron`as @JonStirling says and if you need to see a log you can later connect with `docker exec -itd ContainerID /bin/bash` and do your `tail`s at will...

Comment: Thanks it works well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.
>   (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

Your cron CMD removes the one in php:5.6-apache image. You have to use RUN commands for cron as well.